# how to create player sound UISlider to be UIProgress

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want one application that to play sound file and show it in UIProgress when to play music.
I have to use UISlider instead UIProgress (for example I want can further this sound or Rewind it with UISlider like music player in iphone)

I could create one application that play music with UIProgress but I want could further or rewind this music with touch and push.

please guide me and tell me about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];


durationControl= [[UISlider alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(65, 250 , 130, 10)];
//  durationControl.maximumValue = 130;
[durationControl addTarget:self action:@selector(changeDuration) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[durationControl setThumbImage:[self imageNamed:@"trackbutton"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[durationControl setThumbImage:[self imageNamed:@"trackbutton1"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

[self.view addSubview:durationControl];
}

-(void)ffwAudio{

[player changeDuration:durationControl.value+=5];
durationControl.value = player.currentTime;
}


-(void)bwAudio{

if (durationControl.value>=5) {


    [player changeDuration:durationControl.value-=5];
    durationControl.value = player.currentTime;
}



-(void)changeDuration:(double)value{

player.currentTime = value; 
durationControl.value = player.currentTime;

}
```